# Android RecyclerView auto srcoll to top

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have a layout below

```
<ScrollView>
  <Linearlayout>
     <ViewPager>

     </ViewPager>
  </Linearlayout>
</ScrollView/>
```

And the ViewPager's adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter,the fragment's layout only one recyclerview.

but sometimes when i srcoll the viewpager, the recyclerview will auto scroll to the top.

do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

you are using scroll view and recycler view both parallelly that causes the recycler view to scroll to top even when you scroll a little bit. reason might be that the scrollview' scolling overrides recyclerview'scrolling.

try not to use scroll view with recyclerview

Comment: but the scrollview contain other view, i want the top view scroll with viewpager

Comment: the problem is when i use the viewpager's setCurrentItem, the target page's recyclerview will auto scroll to the top, and not everytime, just sometimes

Comment: set this pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(number of fragment); in your activity's oncreate

Comment: yo can have other views inside scroll view but u might face problem when u place recyclerview inside scrollview